# Change font size of pdf reader

Tags: iphone, ios, font-size

I'm using [Leaves](https://github.com/brow/leaves) library for pdf reader app. How do I change font size, or zoomin and zoomout on that viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution we can use CATiledLayer for tiling the view [Code](https://github.com/hammerlyrodrigo/leaves) its updated Leaves version

Comment: Hi, could you specify how you achieved the font size change.. I am working on a similar library- Pdfkitten..